# Search inside Notes app in OSX 10.8

Tags: macos, search, notes.app

As far as I can tell, the search function in Notes only shows you which notes have that string. Is there a way to find the occurrence of the term **inside** the note itself (without copying to a text editor)?

EDIT: 
<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> Does not show me any in-note searches.
[image]

Comment: That is a bit odd isn't it. Considering all the normal menu items for searching are there but greyed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It appears this solution only works on 10.9 Mavericks…**

---

Select a note, then press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and type your search.

[image: Notes.app Searching]

This will not work for 'pinned' notes that have been opened outside of the Notes app.

Comment: I don't see that view of the notes or the search box. (See edited answer.) What version of the Notes app are you showing there? I have 1.5, with OSX 10.8.4.

Comment: @beroe Oops, seems this was introduced in Mavericks then :( I was sure I'd done this in ML, but obviously not…

Comment: Good to know they fixed it in 10.9. Did they finally make it so that images in notes are synched to your iOS device too?

Comment: is it possible to get the updated version of notes without updating my entire OS?

Answer (score 1):

Just in the interest of tidying up loose ends: 
    It appears this is not possible prior to OSX 10.9 (Mavericks).

Comment: Is the behaviour OP described available after 10.9? Can't seem to find it.

Comment: The method in the accepted answer still works for me in 10.14. I haven't tried in 10.15. You need to have the text of the note visible in the right panel and then a dialog shows up at the top of the screen,

Comment: Sorry, I didn't made myself clear and also didn't note that you are OP :D. What I wanted to ask was is there a way in, say Catalina, to search in all notes?

Comment: The UI is definitely confusing. In my 10.14 version, there is a toolbar above the notes (which can be customized with right-click) and there is a universal search box there. It is the same gray bar that has the close button for the notes window.

Comment: Ohh right, how could I miss that. Thanks a lot!!